# Nested comments in XML?

Tags: xml, comments

Are these nested comments allowed in a XML file?

```
<!-- Making only one observation attempting to correct the error code -->
<!-- <component>
       <!-- Result observation template -->
            <!-- <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5.10" extension="103220"/>
     </component> -->
```

Comment: ... wondering why noone mentioned using [`CDATA`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784183/what-does-cdata-in-xml-mean) as a hacky block comment ...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

No, the string `--` is not permitted to appear within comments in XML.  So the fact you have `--` show up inside another comment is going to cause failures.

And trying to post that answer also broke the text entry parsing  ;)

For further proof, check the W3C specification:

http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-comments

The phrase

> For compatibility, the string " --  " (double-hyphen) MUST NOT occur within comments.]

appears in the first paragraph of the section on XML comments.

Comment: <!-- this is not true -- or is it? -->

Comment: <!-- *it* -- is an error --> System.Xml.XmlException: This is an invalid comment syntax.

Comment: It's to ensure compatibility with SGML.

Comment: @Brent Nash So how do you comment out a big block that has comments in it?

Comment: @DavidDoria Unfortunately, I don't think you can do it easily.  It's like trying to comment out a chunk of code with `/* */` that has another `/* */` nested inside it somewhere.  I think your best bet is to find an XML editor that can auto insert/remove comments for you on a per line basis and fix the few outliers yourself.  It is unpleasant at best.

Comment: @BrentNash I'll take your word for it that it's just to ensure backward compatibility :). Still, for a format designed in the 90s, not allowing nested comments is not cool.

Comment: @BrentWritesCode: Agree with Manav.  The spec *should* have allowed for single-line comments like C and BASIC already had for *DECADES* prior. Then, IDEs (like VS already does with C# even though C# has a multi-line comment feature), keep adding more single-line comment prefixes to each line even if multiple lines are marked for commenting. That's a no brainer. The possibility of the resulting HTML, XML, XAML, etc. being in error is no excuse.  The same problem exists with any programming language that allows single-line (or even multi-line) comments. It's the programmer's responsibility.

Comment: @BrentWritesCode: Yes, but XML is all about nesting things! XML is designed so we can describe nested stuff!!! Didn't they think nesting is a good thing??? (twelve years late comment) :-)

Answer (score 47):

As it is said in [How do I comment out a block of tags in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757396/how-do-i-comment-out-a-block-of-tags-in-xml/14650451#14650451), you can try to wrap your code  with a non-existing processing-instruction, e.g.:

```xml
<?ignore
<component>
       <!-- Result observation template -->
            <!-- <id root="2.16.840.1.113883.19.5.10" extension="103220"/>
     </component> 
?>
```

Comment: This is a great help for cases when badly-behaved NuGet packages mutilate my lovingly curated `web.config` files by adding their own elements and dozens of comments!

Answer (score 5):

In a word - no.

The first encountered end-comment marker will, er... end the comment and the rest of it will look somewhat unpleasant from there on out.

Answer (score 5):

Notepad++ together with the plugin XML Tools can do this.

Select a block of xml and on the xml tools submenu selected "Comment Selection".

Each existing "inner xml comment" will be altered so that it looks like this

```
  <!{1}** inner xml comment **{1}>
```

and if you add another outer comment in this way, those original inner comments will be further altered to

```
  <!{2}** inner xml comment **{2}>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't. `--` both starts and terminates a comment. This makes nesting them impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Without a workaround described below, it's not allowed because [-- can't appear in a comment](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-comments).

Potential solutions:

1. [Visual Studio Code Nested Comments extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=philsinatra.nested-comments)
2. [Notepad++ XML Tools plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53356947/3442232)
3. [Using an XML processing instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35479062/3442232)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I accomplished the task. It's quick and dirty, but it shows the process. It parses properly and uses the NP++ Block comment/uncomment style

Python:

```
dummyCoordinates = [(0,0),(1000,0),(1000,10000),(0,10000),]

comment1 = ET.Comment("<CutoutSubdesign>")
xmlTag.insert(1, comment1)

comment2 = ET.Comment("\t<Polygon>")
xmlTag.insert(2, comment2)

idxCount = 3

for X,Y in dummyCoordinates:
    comment = ET.Comment("\t\t<Point x=\"{:.3f}um\" y=\"{:.3f}um\"/>".format(X,Y))
    xmlTag.insert(idxCount, comment)
    idxCount += 1

comment3 = ET.Comment("\t</Polygon>")
xmlTag.insert(idxCount, comment3)

comment4 = ET.Comment("</CutoutSubdesign>")
xmlTag.insert(idxCount + 1, comment4)
```

Result:

```
<!--<CutoutSubdesign>-->
<!--    <Polygon>-->
<!--        <Point x="0.000um" y="0.000um"/>-->
<!--        <Point x="1000.000um" y="0.000um"/>-->
<!--        <Point x="1000.000um" y="10000.000um"/>-->
<!--        <Point x="0.000um" y="10000.000um"/>-->
<!--    </Polygon>-->
<!--</CutoutSubdesign>-->
```