# How do I comment out a block of tags in XML?

Tags: xml, comments

How do I comment out a block of tags in XML?

I.e. How can I comment out `<staticText>` and everything inside it, in the code below?

```
  <detail>
    <band height="20">
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
        <text><![CDATA[Hello World!]]></text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </detail>
```

I could use `<!-- staticText-->` but that's just for single tags (as what I know), like `//` in Java and C. I would like something more like how `/** comment **/` can be used in Java and C, so I can comment out longer blocks of XML code.

Comment: You should know that **comments within an xml** file are **considered nodes of XmlComment type**. So if you **load the xml** file those **comments nodes are going to get loaded** and it is up to you to avoid them or filter them when parsing the loaded content.

Comment: XML comments are similar to comments in HTML.

Answer (score 1295, accepted):

You can use that style of comment across multiple lines (which exists also in HTML)

```
<detail>
    <band height="20">
    <!--
      Hello,
         I am a multi-line XML comment
         <staticText>
            <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
            <text><![CDATA[Hello World!]]></text>
          </staticText>
      -->
     </band>
</detail>
```

Comment: One caveat with this is that you will have problems with nested comments. You will have to either: (1) remove the trailing ">" on the nested comment's close, or (2) remove the nested comments altogether.

Comment: I have run into problems with (1), as some XML readers (i.e. CruiseControl.NET) may have problems reading a nested comment that has its ">" removed from the end. I ended up having to remove the comments altogether.

Comment: @coderob Actually, even -- is not allowed within XML comments. So you might have to remove the entire -->

Comment: In the Android Studio, select the block, then Ctrl + Slash to comment it (or Ctrl + Shift + Slash).

Comment: One can run into problems using `--` within this type of comment.  Better to use `- ->` if you need to temporarily nest a comment.  In HTML anyway (a subset of xml), including `--` inside a comment is not valid.  *Usually* you can get away with it, but *does sometimes* cause a problem.  So, I be sure to stay clear of multiple `-` in a row within comments, and if I need to temp nest a comment, I'll place spaces between the 2 closing `--` of the `-->`.  This avoids randomly odd errors in XML and HTML.

Comment: One nice thing in IntelliJ when commenting out a block in XML: The nested comment tags get replaced by `&lt;!&ndash;` (`<!--`) and `&ndash;&gt;` (`-->`)

Comment: For anyone wondering, technically XML does not state that nested comments are forbidden, it actually states that using `--` in comments is not allowed (which causes problems with nested comments). This limitation is due to compatibility reasons with SGML, which uses `--` as the comment syntax. Sources: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-comments and https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-compat

Answer (score 217):

You can wrap the text with a non-existing processing-instruction, e.g.:

```
<detail>
<?ignore
  <band height="20">
    <staticText>
      <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
      <text><![CDATA[Hello World!]]></text>
    </staticText>
  </band>
?>
</detail>
```

Nested processing instructions are not allowed and '?>' ends the processing instruction (see http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-pi)

Comment: This method worked exactly how I needed it to, and had the added advantage of working even around internal comments. I'd use this over the accepted answer if you have any form of complicated code.

Comment: This even works with malformed XML inside. So this is a great solution for temporarily commenting out a block.

Comment: Nice. And it's left alone by some source formatter (e.g. Eclipse), unlike multiline `<!-- -->`

Comment: Weird things happen with line endings though after saving, at least in .net.  Just like <!-- -->

Answer (score 152):

If you ask, because you got errors with the `<!-- -->` syntax, it's most likely the CDATA section (and there the `]]>` part), that then lies in the middle of the comment. It *should* not make a difference, but ideal and real world can be quite a bit apart, sometimes (especially when it comes to XML processing).

Try to change the `]]>`, too:

```
  <!--detail>
    <band height="20">
      <staticText>
        <reportElement x="180" y="0" width="200" height="20"/>
        <text><![CDATA[Hello World!]--><!--]></text>
      </staticText>
    </band>
  </detail-->
```

Another thing, that comes to mind: If the content of your XML somewhere contains two hyphens, the comment immediately ends there:

```
<!-- <a> This is strange -- but true!</a> -->
--------------------------^ comment ends here
```

That's quite a common pitfall. It's inherited from the way SGML handles comments. ([Read the XML spec on this topic](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-comments))

Comment: Yes... I always found SGML and XML parsing of comments hard to remember all of the quirks...

Comment: Thanks a lot for mentioning the strange fact with the double hyphens --! I had a case where I commented out a comment. Although I removed the old comment ending, it failed. Example: <!-- ...<code><!-- Old comment </code> ... -->

Comment: To workaround the double-hyphen limitation you can replace `--` with `-&#45;`. It should work the same after uncommenting in most cases.

Answer (score 56):

Actually, you can use the <!--...--> format with multi-lines or tags:

```
<!--
  ...
  ...
  ...
-->
```

Answer (score 37):

Here for commenting we have to write like below:

```
<!-- Your comment here -->
```

#### Shortcuts for IntelliJ Idea and Eclipse

**For Windows & Linux:**

Shortcut for Commenting a single line:

`Ctrl` + `/`

Shortcut for Commenting multiple lines:

`Ctrl` + `Shift` + `/`

**For Mac:**

Shortcut for Commenting a single line:

`cmnd` + `/`

Shortcut for Commenting multiple lines:

`cmnd` + `Shift` + `/`

One thing you have to keep in mind that, you can't comment an attribute of an XML tag. For Example:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <!--android:text="Hello.."-->
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Here, `TextView` is a XML Tag and `text` is an attribute of that tag. You can't comment attributes of an XML Tag. You have to comment the full XML Tag. For Example:

```
<!--<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello.."
    android:textStyle="bold" />-->
```

Answer (score 13):

You can easily comment out the data using this:

```
<!-- 
 <data>
        <data-field1></data-field1>
        <data-field2></data-field2>
        <data-field3></data-field3>
 </data>
-->
```

method of commenting in xml.

Answer (score 11):

Syntax  for XML :
 `<!--Your comment-->`

eg.

> ```
>    <?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" ?>
>    <!--here is your comment :) -->
>    <class_list>   
>    <student>
>    <name></name>
>    <grade>A</grade>
>    </student>
>    </class_list>
> ```

XML Comments Rules

```
Comments cannot appear before XML declaration.
Comments may appear anywhere in a document.
Comments must not appear within attribute values.
Comments cannot be nested inside the other comments.
```

Answer (score 1):

In Notepad++ you can select few lines and use CTRL+Q which will automaticaly make block comments for selected lines.

Comment: In oXygen it's CMD+SHIFT+M on the Mac. Most XML editors should offer something similar.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Eclipse IDE you can comment out lines in an XML file by highlighting them and press Ctrl+Shift+c.