# Xml parser - Getting information inside comment

Tags: java, xml, dom

My objective is to acesse some information inside the xml commented code, in this case, the information inside the tag town.

For a html extract like this:

```
<script type="text/xml">
 <!--
 <world>  
  <city>
   <town>
    London
   </town>
  </city>
  <city>
   <town>
    New York
   </town>
  </city>
 </world>
 -->
</script>
```

I want to get that "London" and "New York".

My code is:

```
   doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("city");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                System.out.println("Town : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("Town").item(0).getTextContent());


            }
        }
```

Yet, this code does not work. BUT, if i remove the comments, it does. Why it doesn't work it comments, and how to fix it?
Thank you!

Comment: A comment is just text..It wont have any internal XML structure. why are you trying to do this with a comment enclosing your XML ?

Comment: Because that's the original XML.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the  element isn't an element of xml in your example, rather it is part of a comment. Why would `doc.getElementsByTagName("city");` parse and return xml nodes from comments?
You can read a bit more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757396/how-do-i-comment-out-a-block-of-tags-in-xml)

Comment: Ok, i understand now. Because that's the original xml I have. So, the best option is to remove the comments with the parser?

Comment: rather, i would go through the lines and remove the ones that make the internal nodes turn into a comment, i.e., `<!--` and `-->`. Then parse the xml.