# How to use XSD Schema with Visual Studio Intellisense on ASP.NET MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc, xsd

I want to use an XSD schema in Visual Studio while hand editing an ASP.NET View .cshtml file so that I can have access the Intellisense functionality for access to the tags and attributes described in the XSD. The file to be output is an XML file to control an embedded device.

Is this possible to do? If so, how?

Are there other tools or other approach that could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was as follows:

1. From Visual Studio Solution explorer, locate the .cshtml file. Right click  menu -> Open With... -> XML editor.
2. Visual Studio main menu XML -> Schemas.. locate or add the desired .xsd schema file.
3. The XML Intellisense may not work well with Razor tags before the root object, eg. @using, @model. To solve this, use an `<?ignore`...`?>` block which will allow the XML tags to properly parse and has no effect on the Razor processing. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14650451/3803219

## Example

```
<?ignore This notation allows the "Intellisense XML autocompletion" to work
    @using...
    @model...
?>
```