# how to disable cron job easily?

Tags: xml, google-app-engine, cron

I have this cron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
  <cron>
    <url>/check</url>
    <description>run my task</description>
    <schedule>every 30 minutes</schedule>
  </cron>  
</cronentries>
```

If I want to stop it from running, can I do the followings?

1) Any way to stop the cron from app-engine ui?

2) If I want to leave the xml for future use, what would I write in the time-interval node? `"never"`

where is the syntax man for this node?

I mean I wasn't sure if `every 1 minutes` or `1 minute` is correct

Or if every `Sunday at 08:00` is defined correctly?

Answer (score 0):

1. AFAIK it's not (yet) possible to disable cron jobs from the developer console. The only way to completely disable it is to comment it out in your xml file (see [How do I comment out a block of tags in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757396/how-do-i-comment-out-a-block-of-tags-in-xml)) and [deploy the updated cron file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#upload-cron). If the cron file contains only that cron job you *might* need to [delete all cron jobs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron#deleting_all_cron_jobs).
2. The [Schedule format](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cronref#schedule_format) doesn't support a `never` keyword (or equivalent). But you can *emulate* it with something rare enough for most practical purposes, like `every 10000 hours`.

You should be able to check the syntax of your cron jobs (and their correct execution, manually triggered) using the admin interface of the development server (or at least the python SDK one does, not 100% certain about the java one)