# How to either uncomment or add a line to an XML/ config file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, windows

I have the following CONFIG file that I need to modify.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings file="%ProgramData%\NCR\RAL\AlhAdmin.exe.config">
        <add key="ConfigurationDataFile" value="AlhAdmin.xml"/>     <!--Config Data Xml File -->
        <!--Log File Details -->
        <!--<add key="ApplicationLogPath" value=""/>-->
        <add key="ApplicationLogName" value="AlhAdmin"/>
        <!--Number of Days to keep log -->
        <add key="ApplicationLogDaysToRetain" value="2"/>
        <!--Port Number to be entered here-->
        <add key="SocketListenPort" value="11000"/>
        <add key="MulticastUDPSendPort" value="11001"/>
        <add key="MulticastUDPSendBroadcastAddress" value="224.168.100.25"/>
        <add key="MulticastUDPListenPort" value="11002"/>
        <add key="MulticastUDPListenBroadcastAddress" value="224.168.100.35"/>
        <add key="DefaultSelTime" value="30"/>
        <add key="DefaultTermSelTime" value="30"/>
        <add key="DefaultLANWaitTime" value="2"/>
        <!--DisplayMessage Form-->
        <add key="MessageDisplayFile" value="DisplayMessages.xml"/>
        <!--RFC: 55071-->
        <add key="UltraVNCFolderPathInFS" value="\ExtData\RAL\UltraVNC"/>
        <add key="StartUpFolderPath" value="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"/>
        <add key="ProgramFileFolderPath" value="C:\Program Files"/>
        <add key="NetworkGroupBMP" value="Network.ico"/>
        <!--RFC: 52790-->
        <add key="DebugLevel" value="25"/>
        <add key="BaseIPToIncr" value="192.168.0"/>
        <add key="BaseIPToIncrSubNet" value="255.255.255.0"/>
        <add key="CheckForConnectedNIC" value="0"/>         <!-- Check for only NICs that are connected /-->
        <add key="AddAdminGroup" value="0"/>
        <add key="SetGatewayInfo" value="1" />    <!-- Wheter order to set the server gateway and DNS entries on the terminal-->
        <add key="CopyRemotely" value="1"/>             <!-- Whether to copy remotely or use Bootdrv share /-->
        <!-- add key="RemoteCopyPort" value="11003" /-->        <!-- Remote copy port on which server is copying /-->
        <!-- add key="ServerIPEntryRequired" value="1" /-->     <!-- Pops the screen to select Server Name/IP /-->
        <!-- add key="QWERTY" value="0" /-->                    <!-- Keyboard style for above screen /-->
        <!-- add key="IPScreenTimeout" value="120" /-->         <!-- Timeout for Server IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="Base1stOctet" value="1" /-->              <!-- Start number for the 1st Octet /-->
        <!-- add key="Default1stOctet" value="1" /-->           <!-- Default 1st Octet for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="Default2ndOctet" value="0" /-->           <!-- Default 2nd Octet for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="Default3rdOctet" value="0" /-->           <!-- Default 3rd Octet for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="Default4thOctet" value="1" /-->           <!-- Default 4th Octet for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="DefaultServerName" value="" /-->          <!-- Default Server Name for IP Screen /-->
        <!-- add key="SetEncryptedPassword" value="1" /-->      <!-- Sets password encrypted /-->
        <add key="SetDefaultDomain" value="0" />    <!-- Sets Default domain in the registry /-->
        <!-- add key="BackupData" value="0" /-->    <!-- Backs up  Data folder over to ExtData\RAL\Data /-->
        <!-- add key="DisableAdmin" value="0" /-->    <!-- disables administrator account  /-->
    </appSettings>
    <startup>

    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/></startup>
    <runtime>
        <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I need to either uncomment the line `<!-- add key="ServerIPEntryRequired" value="1" /-->` or add the same line without it being commented out. Everything I've found is for regular XML files, which this does not seem to be.

Thanks

Comment: That is a regular XML file. There's nothing strange about it at all.

Comment: It's the same, change `<--! something /-->` to `<something/>` in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I comment out a block of tags in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757396/how-do-i-comment-out-a-block-of-tags-in-xml)

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

```
string fileName = "AlhAdmin.exe.config";
string key = "ServerIPEntryRequired";
string value = "1";
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(fileName);

XAttribute xkey = new XAttribute("key", key);
XAttribute xvalue = new XAttribute("value", value);
XElement xElement = new XElement("add", xkey, xvalue);
doc.Descendants("appSettings").Last().Add(xElement);

doc.Save(fileName);
```