# The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors| suite-files)*)"

Tags: java, testng.xml

I have the following `Testng.xml` file, where I've defined two tests in-suite:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
     <suite name="loan">                               //getting error in suite
        <test thread-count="5" name="Loan Dept">
             <classes>
                 <class name="package2.SampleTestNG"/>
                 <class name="package2.Testng2"/>
             </classes>
        </test> <!-- Test -->
      /*<test name="Home Loan">
             <classes>
                 <class name="package2.Testng3"/>   
             </classes>
        </test>*/
    </suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

When I try to comment one of the tests, I am getting the following error:

> The content of element type "suite" must match "(groups?,(listeners|packages|test|parameter|method-selectors| suite-files)*)"

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

- replace all the `/* comment */` and `// comment` with `<!-- comment -->`

This should help you resolve the issue if you are specifically looking to rectify the error caused due to the comments introduced.
The error happens because Suites is not able to understand your commenting design. Check out the answer for this question to see more on commenting in xml code. [How do I comment out a block of tags in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757396/how-do-i-comment-out-a-block-of-tags-in-xml)
There are a couple of other reasons why this error might occur. For e.g if you leave out a comma or any character left out without proper syntax. Try to see your code again make sure all syntax is correct. And use the above method to comment your code. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had the same error but still could run my TestNG tests. I'm not pretty sure that's an error per se. It's because it's something wrong in your testng.xml file, but in simple sight I can't tell you exactly what.